# How to access home directory of Vagrant VM?

Tags: django, vagrant

I started a new Vagrant project to learn some Django. The VM is running well and everything is working, but I don't know how to access the files inside my VM for editing with a text editor like Sublime.

On the VM cd /vagrant gets be into my Desktop Vagrant folder. Yet, I can't find where my VM home directory folders are stored on my host.

/vagrant

```
-Vagrantfile
-cookbooks
--apache2
--apt
--build-essential
--git
--vim
```

~$

```
-build
-django_project
--django_project
--manage.py
-postinstall.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Home directory on your guest is not shared, you need to set it up manually in `Vagrantfile`.

**Edit:**

Look inside of that file and uncomment this line (read the comment above the line to get more details):

```
# config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
```

Comment: How would I do this in the Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 1):

You can shared any folder that you wish. You only have to say into Vagrantfile file what folder you want to share with the guess

In this case I create a folder called **data**, because by default this one non exists. This is my project structure. The data folder and Vagrantfile are at the same directory level.

```ssh
.
├── attributes
├── Berksfile
├── Berksfile.lock
├── chefignore
├── **data**
│   └── **hello**
├── definitions
├── files
│   └── default
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── libraries
├── LICENSE
├── metadata.rb
├── providers
├── README.md
├── recipes
│   ├── default.rb
│   └── gem_sources.rb
├── resources
├── templates
│   └── default
├── test
│   └── integration
│       └── default
├── Thorfile
└── **Vagrantfile**
```

This is the Vagrantfile file configuration.

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04"


  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/vagrant_data"
end
```

All in the data folder is accesible by vagrant_data folder in the guess. You can see the hello file.

```ssh
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop/stack$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Sun Jan 19 13:20:49 2014 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ cd /vagrant_data/
vagrant@ubuntu:/vagrant_data$ ls
hello
vagrant@ubuntu:/vagrant_data$
```

I hope this help you. 
Sorry for my english